# Maven Tomcat Deployment returns HTTP 403 Access Denied, halting production

Tags: java, iphone, maven, tomcat, web

I have configured a  web app to be deployed from my development machine using maven, tomcat 7.0.42, on Ubuntu 12.04 with this build in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://SERVER-IP:8080/manager/html</url>
                    <server>server001</server>
                    <path>/FreeRide-Web</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Also, my settings.xml has this in it:

```
<servers>
<server>
        <id>server001</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</severs>
```

however, when I run "mvn tomcat:deploy -e" it says:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project FreeRide-Web: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://166.78.166.149:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2FFreeRide-Web&war= -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project FreeRide-Web: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://166.78.166.149:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2FFreeRide-Web&war=
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:604)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    ... 23 more
```

Yet, if I go to `http://SERVER-IP:8080/manager/html` in my browser and enter the username and password, it works. So I'm not quite sure what is going on. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue sometime ago and managed to resolve.
You might need to modify the tomcat-users.xml to grant the correct roles for the user.

```
<user username="admin" password="xxxxxxx" roles="manager-script,manager-gui"/>
```

In the pom.xml I have manager/text rather than manager/html

```
<configuration>
  <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>xxxxxx</password>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I already had the user permissions set up in tomcat, but then I changed the url to have "/text" at the end instead of "/html" and it worked. Thank you, so, so much nishantha. You made a friend today !